# Htaccess redirect a specific subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current .htaccess file contains the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I would like to redirect `www.domain.com/category/automotive/used+car+dealers` to  `www.domain.com/category.php?category=automotive&subcategory=used+car+dealers`.

Should be dynamic and not a static redirect, as I will have other categories and subcategories? Can anyone show me some light on how to proceed from here?

I have googled, and browsed Stack Overflow for nearly 2 hours, but I'm still unable to come out with a solution.

[Sample 1]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-+]+)/([\w-+]+)$ category.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I have tweak abit and is able to redirect to the correct file, but somehow the page loads without css and images. please advise. thankyou.

[Sample 2]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /websitefolder/

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-+]+)/([\w-+]+)$ category.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This works fine just that the url will become category.php?category=automotive&subcategory=used+car+dealers instead of /category/automotive/used+car+dealers. but i wish to have the latter. please advise

Comment: I would recommend to use `-` instead of `+` better SEO this way and no hassel of converting in your code

Comment: thanks escomaji, have changed to - instead.

Comment: `-` is better than `_`, but `-` and `+` (space) are both word separators so there should be no difference, SEO wise.

Comment: @Gerben i disagree, since + can be use as %20 or the actual space which sometime can create errors, using the `-` is more accurate

Comment: @EscoMaji I agree that using `-` is better than `+`. It's just that it has noting to do with SEO.

Comment: @Gerben maybe it's from my bad experience then, i use to have _ and spaces and since i moved then to dashes now google,yahoo and bing index them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(category)/([\w-+]+)$ $1.php?$1=$2 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(category)/([\w-+]+)/([\w-+]+)$ $1.php?$1=$2&subcategory=$3 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /websitefolder/

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-+]+)/([\w-+]+)$ category.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Just remove the `R` flag from :

```
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-+]+)/([\w-+]+)$ category.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [R,L]
```

It will not change the URL in the browser.

Comment: hey thinkingmonkey seem to work but i was given the entire path instead http://127.0.0.1/C:/Program%20Files/EasyPHP-5.3.3/www/domain/category.php?category=automotive&subcategory=used+car+dealers

Comment: Hey man you could do melt your two first rewrite rules in one (with `subcategory=''` when first rule is met) ;)

Comment: @OlivierPons Ya ya, I know. Didn't do it thinking that the URL will not look good. :)

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey i have came out with two samples that i have derived at. Can you please help me solve the final mystery?

Comment: @DamianSia You do not want the URL to change in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what should fit your **exactly** your need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?$ category.php?category=$1&subcategory=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

---

Now if you want something more generic, i.e.:

```
www.domain.com/category/automotive/used+car+dealers
=>
www.domain.com/category.php?category=automotive&subcategory=used+car+dealers
```

and

```
www.domain.com/title/automotive/used+car+dealers
=>
www.domain.com/title.php?title=automotive&subcategory=used+car+dealers
```

Please see ThinkingMonkey's answer it's better than mine `:)`.